# How to load XML files using Dropbox.api V2

Tags: c#, xml, dropbox-api

- I migrated my project from Dropbox API version 1 to 2 and it returns error code 400 (Bad request) when I try to load xml file from Dropbox.
- I have read the [documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download) but somehow I still don't understand how to correctly structure version 2 URLs.

What would be the correct V2 url to load an XML file?

I'm loading XML like this:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string uri = new Uri(string.Format(...)).AbsoluteUri;
xmlDoc.Load(uri);
```

**Version 1** (deprecated)

```
string.Format("https://content.dropboxapi.com/1/files/auto{0}?access_token={1}", svcUri, ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

**Version 2** (current)

```
// What is wrong here??
string.Format("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download{0}?access_token={1}", svcUri, ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your version 2 code, you're attempting to put the file path directly on the URL path, and are passing the access token in an `access_token` path. These worked on API v1, but API v2 is a different interface so those won't work there.

In API v2, you're correct that the replacement [is /2/files/download](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download). That's a "content-download endpoint", so the standard way of using that is via a POST with 'Authorization' and 'Dropbox-API-Arg' headers.

To just use a GET with it instead though, as it appears you want to do, i.e., so you can just use a URL by itself, you can use the URL parameters [documented here under "Request and response formats"](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#formats).

So, to access a file at "/folder/filename.xml" the API call parameters for /2/files/download would be:

```
{"path": "/folder/filename.xml"}
```

URL encoding those for use with the `arg` URL parameter, along with the access token information in the `authorization` URL parameter, the result would be:

```
https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download?authorization=Bearer%20ACCESS_TOKEN&arg=%7B%22path%22%3A%20%22%2Ffolder%2Ffilename.xml%22%7D
```

Be sure to replace ACCESS_TOKEN with the actual access token.

Comment: Great, thanks, now I also understand how to structure other Dropbox V2 API calls!